# Need help installing ruby on rails on os x with terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal, installation

I was just setting up my ruby environment using the following guide : http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

No errors with that so I moved onto the next test : http://installfest.railsbridge.org/installfest/create_a_rails_app

(All of these steps listed in the odin project)

but when I type in rails server into terminal I get the following message in terminal :

```
/Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'actionpack' (= 4.2.0) among 75 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0:/Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1311:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `each'
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in `activate'
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `block in gem'
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `synchronize'
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `gem'
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/PeilongDu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to first try doing

```
gem install bundler
```

and then doing `bundle install` in your Rails project's directory.

Comment: I've deleted my answer becuase it was exactly the same as this one

Comment: Tried that and got an even longer error message that's too long to fit here.